# How to get SQL formatted output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL table like this,

```
Column_TEAM
AUS
USA
IND
RUS
```

Expected output is (one team can play against another team only once)

```
AUS vs USA
AUS vs IND
AUS vs RUS
USA vs IND
USA vs RUS
IND vs RUS
```

I tried to with Rank() function, no success. 
could please help me in SQL Server or in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to self-join your table as follows:

```
-- SQL Server concatenation syntax
SELECT a.Column_TEAM + ' vs ' + b.Column_TEAM
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b ON a.Column_TEAM < b.Column_TEAM

-- PostgreSQL concatenation syntax
SELECT a.Column_TEAM || ' vs ' || b.Column_TEAM
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b ON a.Column_TEAM < b.Column_TEAM
```

Comment: @Ananda-SteelTownBoy You can also use `CROSS JOIN` (I'm guessing it would also be new to you); and `WHERE a.Column_TEAM <> b.Column_TEAM`

Comment: @Ananda-SteelTownBoy: Yeah, joins are an interesting topic. [I've recently written an article on all sorts of different join types](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/12/a-probably-incomplete-comprehensive-guide-to-the-many-different-ways-to-join-tables-in-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using a simple inner join as well. here you go...

```
SELECT T2.CTRY2,T1.CTRY1
FROM 
(SELECT CTRY AS CTRY1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CTRY) AS R1 FROM (VALUES ('AUS'),('USA'),('IND'),('RUS') ) CT (CTRY)) T1

JOIN 

(SELECT CTRY AS CTRY2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CTRY) AS R2 FROM (VALUES ('AUS'),('USA'),('IND'),('RUS') ) CT (CTRY)) T2

ON T1.R1 > T2.R2
ORDER BY T1.CTRY1 ASC
```